# Swift: Ensure urlSession.dataTask is completed in my function before passing result

Tags: swift, xcode

Hello I have this function:

```
func planAdded(id:Int, user_id:Int) -> Int {
    let locationURL = "myurl"
    var planResult: Int = 0
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: locationURL)!)
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:{
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let error = error {
                print (error)
                return
            }

            if let data = data {

                let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                planResult = responseString!.integerValue

            }
        }


    })

    task.resume()
   print(planResult)

    return planResult
}
```

What I am trying to do is to ensure that I got the result for planResult in tableView cellforrow at indexpath function.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   ...
    case 4:



        if (result == 1){
           ...
        } else if (result == 2){
           ...
        } else {
           ...
        }


    default:
        cell.fieldLabel.text = ""
    }

    return cell

}
```

Here is my viewDidLoad function

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.result =  self.planAdded(1, 2)
}
```

For some reasons, this keeps returning 0; however, the print line is actually printing correct value. I did some research and I believe this is because of asychonous call of the dataTask. Is there a way I ensure that my function is actually completed and return the value for the indexpath function?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is, you are doing it in a wrong way! Because, once you intialize the `class` the `UIViewController` lifecycle starts. Once the `viewDidLoad()` is called it the `UITableView` is also updated with no data.

Also, you are calling API to get the data, you need to notify `UITableViewDataSource` to update data and here is how you can do that!

```
func planAdded(id:Int, user_id:Int) {
    let locationURL = "myurl"
    var planResult: Int = 0
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: locationURL)!)
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:{
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

        DispatchQueue.main.async {

            if let error = error {
                print (error)
                return
            }

            if let data = data {

                let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
                self.result = responseString!.integerValue
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

And you are getting `zero` value because it's an `async` method. So get the data you need to use `completionCallback`.

```
func planAdded(id:Int, user_id:Int, completion: (result: Int) -> ()) {
    let locationURL = "myurl"
    var planResult: Int = 0
    let request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: locationURL)!)
    let urlSession = URLSession.shared
    let task = urlSession.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler:{
        (data, response, error) -> Void in

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        if let error = error {
            print (error)
            return
        }

        if let data = data {

            let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
            planResult = responseString!.integerValue
            completion(planResult)            
          }
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}
```

> Usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    planAdded(1, 2){(value) in
        self.result = value
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: yes now the correct value is returned although the table has to reload twice. I got one more question. When the result == 1, I created a button and add it as subview. cell.addSubview(myButton). However, when I reload the table and the result == 2,  the button didn't disappear. Is there a way I can clear it? Thanks.