# Swift Function Returning Value Before It has finished processing

Tags: ios, swift, function, swift3, nsurlsession

Basically I have a code for posting simple data to a server and will return a boolean value `success` if the post request was successful but it seems to be that the boolean value is returned before even the data is processed, am I doing something wrong?

```
public func postRequest(rawText: String) -> Bool {
    var success = true
    let destUrl = "http://api.getquesto.com:8080/upload/"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: destUrl)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = rawText
    request.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
//    request.setValue("compute", forHTTPHeaderField: "Questo-Query")
//    request.setValue("Fuck you", forHTTPHeaderField: "quizTitle")

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    print(request.httpBody!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            success = false
            print(success)

            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: UInt(0))) as? [String: Any] {
                print("json \(json)")
            } else {
                print("can not cast data")
                success = false

            }
        } catch let error {
            print("cant parse json \(error)")
            success = false
            print(success)

        }

        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        //print(dataString)
        //print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        constantVariables.rawQuestionData = dataString as! String
        let processedResults = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: " ")
        print("processed results = " + (processedResults! as String))
        let newArray = processedResults!.components(separatedBy: ", \"")
        //print(newArray)

        for index in 0...(newArray.count - 1) {
            if index%2 == 0 {
                constantVariables.questions.insert(newArray[index].replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: ""), at: index/2)

                //        ConstantsArray.questionArray.append(newArray[index])
                //        print("question array: " + ConstantsArray.answerArray[index/2])
            }else{
                constantVariables.answers.insert(newArray[index].replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: ""), at: (index-1)/2)

                //        ConstantsArray.questionArray.append(newArray[index])
                print("answer array: " + constantVariables.answers[(index-1)/2])

            }
        }
    }
    task.resume()
    print(success)
    return success
    }
```

Comment: `URLSessionDataTask` is asynchronous, when you call `resume()` your code will continue and task starts in two parallel threads. If you want it to be synchronous, make an extension with code similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34308158/2122979

Comment: More similar questions with answers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40810108/swift-http-request-use-urlsession, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40811500/ios-swift-value-of-an-integer-is-not-being-saved, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40756123/swift-ensure-urlsession-datatask-is-completed-in-my-function-before-passing-res, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40491502/swift-3-send-make-synchronous-http-request, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is happening because the function directly returns the value of `success`, `dataTask` works *asynchronously*, so, the function should NOT wait until `dataTask` finishes the parsing to edit the value of `success`, i.e: `return success` is executed before `dataTask` edits the value of `success`.

I suggest to let the function handles a *`completion`* closure instead of direct returning of `Bool`.

Your function should be similar to:

```
public func postRequest(rawText: String, completion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> ()) {
    var success = true
    let destUrl = "http://api.getquesto.com:8080/upload/"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: destUrl)!)
    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let postString = rawText
    request.setValue("text/plain", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
    //    request.setValue("compute", forHTTPHeaderField: "Questo-Query")
    //    request.setValue("Fuck you", forHTTPHeaderField: "quizTitle")

    request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)
    print(request.httpBody!)
    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, response, error in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else {                                                 // check for fundamental networking error
            print("error=\(error)")
            success = false
            print(success)

            return
        }

        if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {           // check for http errors
            print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
            print("response = \(response)")
        }

        let responseString = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
        do {
            if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions(rawValue: UInt(0))) as? [String: Any] {
                print("json \(json)")
            } else {
                print("can not cast data")
                success = false

            }
        } catch let error {
            print("cant parse json \(error)")
            success = false
            print(success)

        }

        print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        let dataString = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
        //print(dataString)
        //print("responseString = \(responseString)")
        constantVariables.rawQuestionData = dataString as! String
        let processedResults = dataString?.replacingOccurrences(of: "\\n", with: " ")
        print("processed results = " + (processedResults! as String))
        let newArray = processedResults!.components(separatedBy: ", \"")
        //print(newArray)

        for index in 0...(newArray.count - 1) {
            if index%2 == 0 {
                constantVariables.questions.insert(newArray[index].replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: ""), at: index/2)

                //        ConstantsArray.questionArray.append(newArray[index])
                //        print("question array: " + ConstantsArray.answerArray[index/2])
            }else{
                constantVariables.answers.insert(newArray[index].replacingOccurrences(of: "\"", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "]", with: "").replacingOccurrences(of: "[", with: ""), at: (index-1)/2)

                //        ConstantsArray.questionArray.append(newArray[index])
                print("answer array: " + constantVariables.answers[(index-1)/2])

            }
        }

        completion(success)
    }
    task.resume()
    print(success)
}
```

In Swift 3, you should use `@escaping`, for more information, you might want to check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39063499/updating-closures-to-swift-3-escaping).

Calling:

```
postRequest(rawText: "rawText", completion: { success in
    print(success)
})
```

Now, it should wait untill `dataTask` finish it's parsing, and then, the code in the `completion` will be called.

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked well!

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks for showing how to call the function too!